# Last word in a sentence is not printing after the sentence is reversed

Tags: c++

When I am reversing a sentence, below code is unable to print the last  word  in the sentence after it is reversed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char sentence[80]={0};
    cout<<"Input the string: ";
    cin.getline(sentence,80,'\n');

    int length=strlen(sentence);
    int check=0;
    for(int i=length; i>0; i--)
    {
        if(sentence[i]!=' ')
        {
            check++;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=i; j<(check+i); j++)
                cout<<sentence[j+1];
            cout<<" ";
            check=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If we enter the Sentence as "My Name is Rakesh" the output it is displaying as "Rakesh is Name". It is not displaying "My".

Comment: Don't we have a `C-style C++` tag for questions up here? If we don't, we really should. Would save lots of confusion.

Comment: _@prakash_ What's `"conio.h"` and why it's needed with your code?

Comment: yaa..yes it is not required here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two mistakes in your code.

**Mistake # 01:**

You are not iterating over the whole input. You are skipping the first index of the array because of the statement `i>0`.

**Possible Solution:**

You should change the condition of loop from `i>0` to `i>=0` in order to iterate the whole input.

**Mistake # 02:**

You are not checking the case of *first* word of the input, which is `My` in your case. You are printing the word in case the condition of `sentence[i]!=' '` gets false so what if `sentence[0]` is not a space character then the statement `check++` will be executed and then the loop will be terminated so the first word of input will not be printed.

**Possible Solution:**

You should handle this case either by printing the word outside the loop or by adding an `if` condition in the loop to print the word in case if `i == 0 && sentence[i] != ' '`. I have updated the code according to the first method and now it works fine.

**Updated Code:**

```
    int i = 0;
    for (i = length; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (sentence[i] != ' ')
        {
            check++;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = i; j<(check + i); j++)
                cout << sentence[j + 1];
            cout << " ";
            check = 0;
        }
    }


    //Printing the missing word outside the loop
    for (int j = i; j<(check + i); j++)
        cout << sentence[j + 1];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Itban

Answer (score 0):

If you begin and end your sentence with a `space` character it will work.  You need to treat the `space` character and your end of string (`null` terminator) and your start of string as the same delimiter in this case, so you detect the start of the string, end of the string as well as the spaces in between

> Try entering: " My Name is Rakesh "  (with a space at the start and end)

to see the scope of your problem...Use a debugger to step through
(You indirectly manage the null termintor - by using `strlen`; and you capture all the `space` characters, but what do you do with the string remaining, that is the word delimited by being at the beginning of the String - at index 0)

Comment: Excellent.  Trim off excess spaces and try again, remember your start and end points are just as important as the spaces you are detecting

Comment: Also, the last word - the one you are missing, is best treated as a special case and dealing with it after your loops (assuming you have one word or more in your input string)

Comment: Hi Grantly. when we give space at the begin and end of the sentence i am able to get the complete sentence in reverse order. But why it is happening like this?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
for(int i=length; i>0; i--)
```

ends when i=1, and array index starts from 0, so that's ONE of problems here.

Change i>0 to i>=0.

Comment: Would you suggest also to change i=length to i=length-1.... Or change i--, to --i....  Yes plenty of problems here :)  Welcome OP - to Stackoverflow :)